# underlined package statement for java on each class / interface

Tags: java, package

for java, what does it mean if you have a

```
package name;

//code under neath and such

////
////
////
////
////
////
```

and the "name" is underlined in red in all of the classes / interfaces?

Comment: what does it say when you hover on underline?

Comment: oh yeah ; incorrect package.. however this file came zipped for something i want to work on

Comment: probably given package does not correspond to folder in which these classes resides.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the package statement at the top tells you that you're in a java package, more specifically, what package you are in. Basically, a package is a way of separating code. If it's underlined, that means you're not in the package that you're telling it you are in. To fix your problem, put a folder in your src folder called name and put your code there.